# Base64 decoding differences

Tags: java, flutter, base64

I've been trying to figure out why Base64 decoding is different between Dart and Java.

Dart example code

```
import 'dart:convert';
var str = '640gPKMxZZbeLDIUeXiZmg==';
var dec = base64.decode(str);
print(dec);
```

prints: [235, 141, 32, 60, 163, 49, 101, 150, 222, 44, 50, 20, 121, 120, 153, 154]

Java example code

```
import java.util.Base64;
String str = "640gPKMxZZbeLDIUeXiZmg==";
byte[] dec = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dec));
```

prints: [-21, -115, 32, 60, -93, 49, 101, -106, -34, 44, 50, 20, 121, 120, -103, -102]

Any ideas? As far as I'm aware they both implement RFC4648.

For the Dart code, I did try using base64url and the normalize function which didn't change anything (to be expected I suppose). Not too sure what else to try.

Comment: Note that Java bytes are signed. Try printing the unsigned equivalents (for a byte, `b & 0xff`) https://ideone.com/fxM9Uq.

Comment: They are the same bytes. It's just that Java doesn't have unsigned bytes. The byte 235 in Java *is* -21.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help! I'll try to figure something out from that.